# wildcards in node-http-proxy router table

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

can somebody tell me how to use wildcards in the router table of node-http-proxy?

for example for wildcard subdomains, something like *.domain.de
i know there are RegEx used but i cant get it to work.
i tried like

```
'([a-zA-Z0-9_]).domain.de': '127.0.0.1:8085',
```

and

```
 '([^.]*).domain.de' : '127.0.0.1:8085'
```

but none seem to redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not done this myself but I would think that the whole string needs to be a regular expression. So it would be something like:

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9_]\.domain\.de': '127.0.0.1:8085',
```

Note the escaping of the dots. In fact, this would be simpler (though perhaps not as secure) if that format is correct:

```
'.*\.domain\.de': '127.0.0.1:8085',
```

Or even:

```
'\w*\.domain\.de': '127.0.0.1:8085',
```

Sadly, and as usual with all things Node, you are expected to "know" this stuff - mainly by reading the source code :( This is one of the key issues that puts me off using Node in the real world.

Comment: im afraid but that doesnt work. the regex pattern seems correct but i have the impression the match isnt forwarded correctly, could that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm slightly busy just now, I'll try to get a more definitive answer soon.

Comment: alright thanks for your recherche. i try to formulate a feature request then

Comment: This is a limitation of JSON as the key has to be explicit in order for values to be properly identified. Don't hold your breath for a feature release =)

Comment: This feature has now been added so Regular Expressions will work for the routing path.

Comment: Great! Should make this much more usable. Thanks for the info @DJohnson